# Perl : Get offset between gmtime and localtime when input time in seconds since epoch which considers daylight savings time

Tags: perl, epoch

I want to get the offset in hours between localtime and gmtime given microseconds since epoch. What I have so far is something like this

```
# Microseconds since Epoch 
my $msec = 555329743301750;

# Convert to seconds 
my $sec = $msec/1000000;

my $val = (POSIX::mktime(localtime $sec) - POSIX::mktime(gmtime $sec)) / 60 / 60;

print "$val\n";
```

1) The output I get is -6.(CST localtime) However I am expecting -5. The behavior I am expecting is something similar to the result from running bash command

```
`date -d 20190514 "+%z"`;
```

2) Long story short, how do I compute offset similar to the `date -d 20190514 "+%z"` in perl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to get the UTC offset in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143528/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-utc-offset-in-perl)

Comment: Worst case, you can also subtract the `isdst` value. `my @tmp =  localtime($sec); $val = $val - $tmp[8];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the core [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

# Microseconds since Epoch 
my $usec = 555329743301750;

# Convert to seconds 
my $sec = $usec/1000000;

my $offset = localtime($sec)->tzoffset / 3600;
```

Time::Moment and DateTime can also return this value, if you construct them as I showed on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56385685/5848200).

```
my $offset = $time_moment->offset / 60;

my $offset = $datetime->offset / 3600;
```

You can also create these objects from dates, but it will of course give you the offset at midnight (local time) on that day.

```
use Time::Piece;
my $time = localtime->strptime('20190514', '%Y%m%d');

use Time::Moment;
use Role::Tiny ();
my $class = Role::Tiny->create_class_with_roles('Time::Moment', 'Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone');
my $time = $class->new(year => 2019, month => 5, day => 14)->with_system_offset_same_local;

use DateTime;
my $time = DateTime->new(year => 2019, month => 5, day => 14, time_zone => 'local');
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a few follow up questions. 1) If I know the date then what is the best approach? 2) Could you point out the issue with my implementation. I don't quite understand the reason it would not account for daylight savings.

Comment: Added examples of constructing each object from a date. I am not sure what the issue is with your implementation, but perhaps you need something similar to how [with_system_offset_same_instant](https://metacpan.org/source/Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone#L31-36) determines the offset to set.

Comment: `use Time::Piece;
my $time = localtime->strptime('20190514', '%Y%m%d');
my $offset = localtime($sec)->tzoffset / 3600;`
This runs into the same issue are my original implementation. Don't get the daylight savings difference. I cant use Time::Moment or DateTime since they are not installed and may not be.

Comment: @EternalLearner You created two different Time::Piece objects. Make sure you call tzoffset on the one you meant to.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the same [+-]HHMM format as the Linux "%z" format:

```
use POSIX qw[mktime];

my $tz = (localtime time)[8] * 60 - mktime(gmtime 0) / 60;
$tz = sprintf "%+03d%02d\n", $tz / 60, abs($tz) % 60;
```

If you just want the offset in hours, you can do this:

```
my $tz_offset_hours = (localtime time)[8] - mktime(gmtime 0)) / 3600;
```

---

**Bonus:** The following subroutine will return a full timestamp with time zone offset and microseconds, as in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.nnnnnn [+-]HHMM":

```
use POSIX qw[mktime strftime];
use Time::HiRes qw[gettimeofday];

sub timestamp () {
  my @now = gettimeofday;
  my $tz  = (localtime $now[0])[8] * 60 - mktime(gmtime 0) / 60;
  my $ts  = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime $now[0]);
  return sprintf "%s.%06d %+03d%02d", $ts, $now[1], $tz / 60, abs($tz) % 60;
}
```